# I want to make my #menu button of my project website works like switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello stackoverflow fellows
I am still working on my gallery website.
there is #menu button will show up when the screen is smaller than 640px
but when I cursor on it it gives me the new nav, but when I move the cursor out of eaither nav, #menu , it will close the navigation but i want to make it open the navigation until I click the #menu again. I heard many people try to make the website responsive with CSS3. I found out :active selector does not solve this problem
Also, when I go the website http://kyu317.dothome.co.kr/, internet explorer draw pupple?blue lines outside of the png image... I don't have any idea of it.\
Thanks for reading my post and Please comment and critic me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showhome").click(function(){
        $(".home").show();
        $(".Profile").hide();
        $(".Gallery").hide();
        $(".Contact").hide();
    });
    $(".showProfile").click(function(){
        $(".home").hide();
        $(".Profile").show();
        $(".Gallery").hide();
        $(".Contact").hide();
    });
    $(".showGallery").click(function(){
        $(".home").hide();
        $(".Profile").hide();
        $(".Gallery").show();
        $(".Contact").hide();
    });
    $(".showContact").click(function(){
        $(".home").hide();
        $(".Profile").hide();
        $(".Gallery").hide();
        $(".Contact").show();
    });
    // Hide all and show home on page loading
    $(".home").show();
    $(".Profile").hide();
    $(".Gallery").hide();
    $(".Contact").hide();
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: font1;
  src: url('fonts/CaviarDreams.woff');
}
#wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 background: white;
 border:1px solid white;
 max-width: 1000px;
}

header {
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 76px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

#logo {
 margin-top: 37px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 160px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url(logo6.png) no-repeat center;
 display: block; 
}
 
nav {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 27px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 }
 
nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 font-family: font1; 
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover {
 color: #6F6F6F;
}

#menu{
 display: hidden;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: url(menu-icon.png) center;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
 
 #menu {
  display:inline-block;  
 }
 
 #menu:hover, nav:hover {
  background-color: #CBCBCB;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
 }
 
 nav ul {  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #CBCBCB;
  right: 19px;
  top: 57px;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  z-index: 200;
 } 
 
 #menu:hover, nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
 }
 
 nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
}

#swap{
 margin: 40px 10px 40px;
 max-width: 980px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid white;
 z-index:100;
 overflow: hidden;
}
/* home */
 .home img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 }

 /* gallery */
.Gallery li{
 font-family: century gothic;
 font-size: 12px;
 display: block; 
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.Gallery img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/* footer */
#sns {
 text-align: center;
}
#sns li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#copyright li{
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center; 
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="header-site" role="banner">
   <a href="#" id="logo" class=showhome></a>
   <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu"></a>
    <ul>
     <li class=showProfile>Profile</li>
                    <li class=showGallery>Gallery</li>
                    <li class=showContact>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="swap">
   <div id="Home_contents"    class=home > <img src="images/home.png"> </div>
            <div id="Profile_contents" class=Profile >Profile contents</div>
            <div id="Gallery_contents" class=Gallery >      
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Flower @CSUN Farmer's Market</li>
          
      <img src="images/2.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Nissan PGC10 @Motor show</li>
          
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Fixie @Encino Velodrom</li>
          
      <img src="images/4.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Parents @In_cheon Int. Airport</li>
          
      <img src="images/5.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Melrose St. @Hollywood</li>
     
      <img src="images/6.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Street near LACMA @Los Angeles </li>    
      
   </div>
            <div id="Contact_contents" class=Contact >Contact contents</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
   <div id="sns">
   <li>
    <a class="Facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/verdi.park.1" target=" _blank"><img src="FACEBOOK.png"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="instagram-icon" href="https://instagram.com/ipark317/" target=" _blank"><img src="INSTAGRAM.png"></a>
   </li>
   </div>
   <div id="copyright">
    <li> COPYRIGHT © 2015 INKYU PARK.<br>ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. </li>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!-- Must have this line first, to enable functions in test.js -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Here you get the hide/show functions -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `content: menu;` to your menu in media query `@media all and (max-width:640px)` like this

```
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
  #menu {
    display:inline-block;  
    content: menu; 
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: font1;
  src: url('fonts/CaviarDreams.woff');
}
#wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 background: white;
 border:1px solid white;
 max-width: 1000px;
}

header {
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 76px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

#logo {
 margin-top: 37px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 160px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url(logo6.png) no-repeat center;
 display: block; 
}
 
nav {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 27px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 }
 
nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 font-family: font1; 
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover {
 color: #6F6F6F;
}

#menu{
 display: hidden;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: url(menu-icon.png) center;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
 
 #menu {
  display:inline-block;  
      content: menu;
 }
 
 #menu:hover, nav:hover {
  background-color: #CBCBCB;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
 }
 
 nav ul {  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #CBCBCB;
  right: 19px;
  top: 57px;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  z-index: 200;
 } 
 
 #menu:hover, nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
 }
 
 nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
}

#swap{
 margin: 40px 10px 40px;
 max-width: 980px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid white;
 z-index:100;
 overflow: hidden;
}
/* home */
 .home img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 }

 /* gallery */
.Gallery li{
 font-family: century gothic;
 font-size: 12px;
 display: block; 
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.Gallery img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/* footer */
#sns {
 text-align: center;
}
#sns li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#copyright li{
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center; 
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="header-site" role="banner">
   <a href="#" id="logo" class=showhome></a>
   <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu"></a>
    <ul>
     <li class=showProfile>Profile</li>
                    <li class=showGallery>Gallery</li>
                    <li class=showContact>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="swap">
   <div id="Home_contents"    class=home > <img src="images/home.png"> </div>
            <div id="Profile_contents" class=Profile >Profile contents</div>
            <div id="Gallery_contents" class=Gallery >      
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Flower @CSUN Farmer's Market</li>
          
      <img src="images/2.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Nissan PGC10 @Motor show</li>
          
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Fixie @Encino Velodrom</li>
          
      <img src="images/4.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Parents @In_cheon Int. Airport</li>
          
      <img src="images/5.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Melrose St. @Hollywood</li>
     
      <img src="images/6.jpg">
      <li>GX1 20mm #Street near LACMA @Los Angeles </li>    
      
   </div>
            <div id="Contact_contents" class=Contact >Contact contents</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
   <div id="sns">
   <li>
    <a class="Facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/verdi.park.1" target=" _blank"><img src="FACEBOOK.png"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="instagram-icon" href="https://instagram.com/ipark317/" target=" _blank"><img src="INSTAGRAM.png"></a>
   </li>
   </div>
   <div id="copyright">
    <li> COPYRIGHT © 2015 INKYU PARK.<br>ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. </li>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!-- Must have this line first, to enable functions in test.js -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Here you get the hide/show functions -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery

```
$('#menu ul li')
.css({cursor: "pointer"})
.on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})
```

(or) By using CSS follow this article.

http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/